# How to hide a larger element inside a table cell - CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<table>` with 3 cells (`<td>`), each cell with 150px width and 100px height. I placed a `<a>` having height 100px, width 200px, display:block, inside a cell. But then the table cell resized into 200px showing the entire div. But I just want to see only a portion of div and the cell may remain as such, 150px wide.

html;

```
<table class="mytable">
  <td class="cell">
    <a class="wrapper">sometext</a>
  </td>
  <td class="cell">aa</td>
  <td class="cell">bb</td>
</table>
```

css;

```
.mytable{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.mytable tr td{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try adding overflow:hidden; to the styling.. Also add mode code. Show us the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Basically you add a `position: 'relative';` to the td's and a `position:'absolute';` to the span or anchor tags.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a>Hello</a></td>
        <td><a>World</a></td>
        <td><a>Hi</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
}
td{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Here is the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ8QA/3/)